# How to grep a block of text?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to delete a block of specific server from this file

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "documentroot"
ServerName newserver
</VirtualHost>
```

So far I've used the following, but it doesn't seem to give me the proper result, but instead greps for each line of the block (of the inner grep) individually.

```
grep -vF "$(grep -w -B 2 -A 1 'newserver'/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf)" /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf;
```

The above results in the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
```

While instead I want the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one with `diff` and parts of your initial command:

```
diff  <(grep -w -B 2 -A 1 'newserver' /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf) \
      /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf  | 
grep -e '^> ' | sed -e 's/^> //'
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! It works like a charm! Quite simple and I just looked into grep -e and sed, kind of get it. Thanks!

Comment: I get a problem when the code if it's the last line in the file. It keeps the last line without deleting it. For example, `</VirtualHost>` stays.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: If the file ends with this a blank space or a new line at the end,
then the code will work fine. However, if the file ends without any extra lines, as in `</VirtualHost>` is the last line of the file, then the said `</VirtualHost>` will not be deleted. The error only occurs of the searched block is at the end of the file. I tried putting it between two blocks, and it worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't reproduce the problem. for me it works even if the block is at the end of the file. Does that mean, you end up with two times "</VirtualHost>" at the end of the file?

Comment: Exactly. I fixed it by adding the -b tag to the diff command. Thank you so much! Saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 2):

awk alone:

```
$ awk '!/ServerName newserver/{printf "%s%s", $0, RS}' RS='</VirtualHost>' file

NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
</VirtualHost>
```

`RS` defines `</VirtualHost>` as record separator and `awk` will prints those records(`$0`) that doesn't match with `ServerName newserver` in it. And then print the `RS`(`</VirtualHost>`) again which is removed when we change RS to that.

Comment: I keep getting this error:
`</awk: not enough args in printf(IfModule log_config_module>`

Comment: I should add that the file contains more text... The part I want to filter out (which I've included here) is only a part of the file text. Maybe that's the issue? Oh, and I'm running OSX.

Comment: I tried this `awk '!/ServerName newserver/{printf $0 RS}' RS='</' /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf;`

Comment: Yeah, there is. You may find the file here: http://yaharga.com/httpd.txt
The said string is at line 300. Thanks again!

Comment: @yaharga fixed. I needed to use printf control characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tac vhost | awk 'NR>4' | tac
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
</VirtualHost>
```

This is a 'trick' to remove the last Vhost by the known numbers of lines it contains

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the specific block be removed by what the **ServerName** is. It's a variable, can be the second, third, last, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete an entry with **ServerName newserver** then use this perl one-liner:

```
perl -0pe 's~(?s)\s?<VirtualHost[^>]*>((?!</VirtualHost>).)*ServerName newserver.*</VirtualHost>~~' file
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web"
ServerName bedrock
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Using a variable:**

```
s='newserver'
perl -0pe 's~(?s)\s?<VirtualHost[^>]*>((?!</VirtualHost>).)*ServerName '"$s"'.*</VirtualHost>~~' file
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY2hJ7/1)

#### Explanation:

This perl command uses a regex that matches a block starting from these 2 tags:

```
<VirtualHost[^>]*>
```

and

```
</VirtualHost>
```

and finds this pattern in between these 2 patterns:

```
ServerName newserver
```

It uses a negative lookahead pattern using `(?!</VirtualHost>)` that makes sure only when `ServerName` test comes then only match is found.

Comment: What if **newserver** was a variable say **$answer**? Also, could you explain what this code does? Or which functions you're using, at least? Thanks!

Comment: See updated answer with use of a variable + explanation + a demo link.

Comment: What is '(?s)' in the regex ?

Comment: That is `DOTALL` flag to make dot match newlines.