# Getting extra line when output to file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, diff

I'm using a diff command and it's printing out to a file. The file keeps getting an extra line in the end that I don't need to appear. How can I prevent it from being there?

The command is as follows:

```
diff -b <(grep -B 2 -A 1 'bedrock.local' /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf) /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf > test.txt
```

The file being used is here (thought I don't think it matters): http://yaharga.com/httpd.txt

Perhaps at least I'd like to know how to check the last line of the file and delete it only if it's blank.

Comment: There's only one file argument given to `diff` in that command.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: You are diffing part of a file against the whole file?

Comment: Yes. This is sort of a follow up to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406596/how-to-grep-a-block-of-text

Comment: I can't reproduce an extra line using the sample file from the other question. What is the output of that `grep` command? What are the contents of that httpd.conf file (the linked file doesn't have `bedrock.local` in it at all). What do you mean an extra line exactly? Just a blank line below the last line in the original file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just an extra blank line. The names of the variables were changed. In the linked file "newserver" at the end of the file is supposed to be the "bedrock.local" of my new file.

Comment: Running the exact command from your post against that file and using `newserver` in the grep I don't get an extra line in the test.txt file.

Comment: I just tried echoing to a file and it gave me an extra line. Any idea what else this might be related to? Basically whenever I output to a file (`echo string > file`) it has to have an extra blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete empty last line you can use sed, it will delete it only if it's blank:

```
sed '${/^\s*$/d;}' file
```

Ok i made research with your file on my MacOS.
I created file new.conf by `touch new.conf` and then copied data from your file to it.
btw i checked file and didn't have extra empty line at the bottom of it.
I wrote script script.sh with following:

```
diff -b <(grep -B 2 -A 1 'bedrock.local' new.conf) new.conf > test.txt
sed -i.bak '1d;s/^>//' test.txt
```

It diffed what was needed and deleted first useless row and all `>` saving it to a new file `test.txt`

I checked again and no extra empty line was presented.

Additionaly i would suggest you to try and delete the extra line you have like this: `sed -i.bak '$d' test.txt`
And check a number of lines before and after `sed = test.txt`

Probably your text editor somehow added this extra line to your file. Try something else - `nano` for example or `vi`

Comment: it depends on how you using it and if your last line really blank

Comment: I just tried echoing a random string into the file and it still adds an extra line. `echo asdf > test.txt`. By extra line I mean it's just blank, as if you've hit enter (or return) and just stopped. Just a new line.

Comment: use sed = file . it will show number for each line. I have file with 10 lines, last line is empty, i run sed i provided and see 9 lines.

Comment: It says 605 but when I open it in Sublime Text it tells me there are 606 lines.

Comment: try this: sed '${/^\s*$/d;}' file > newfile and then check new file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66696/discussion-between-sandyelms-and-yaharga).